# How use linq explict in powershell or analogue of "NOT IN" in SQL

Tags: linq, powershell, datatable

I have a question about using Linq in PowerShell. I can not figure out how to correctly use the `Except` method

Example tables:

```
$Arr = 1..1000
$Props = ("employeeID","FindName1","FindName2")
$Table1 = New-Object System.Data.DataTable "Table1"
$Props | ForEach-Object { $Table1.Columns.Add( $_ , [String]) | Out-Null }

ForEach ($Record in $Arr ) {
    $Row = $Table1.NewRow()
    $Row.employeeID = $Record.ToString("00000")
    $Row.FindName1 = "UserName_" + $Record.ToString()
    $Row.FindName2 = "String_" + $Record.ToString("00000000")
    $Table1.Rows.Add($Row)
}

$Arr2 = 980..1111
$Props = ("employeeID","FindName1")
$Table2 = New-Object System.Data.DataTable "Table2"
$Props | ForEach-Object { $Table2.Columns.Add( $_ , [String]) | Out-Null }

ForEach ($Record in $Arr2 ) {
    $Row = $Table2.NewRow()
    $Row.employeeID = $Record.ToString("00000")
    $Row.FindName1 = "UserName_" + $Record.ToString()
    $Table2.Rows.Add($Row)
}
```

As a result of the work, I want to get records from the `$table1` where FindName1 not in `$Table2.FindName1`, **preserving all the headers**

An attempt to perform does not produce the expected result.

```
$ExceptOut = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Except($Table1.FindName1, $Table2.FindName1)
```

As I understood from the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except) , i need to create my own class with methods that allow me to use a LINQ in the tables. But I am extremely far from programming. Or maybe there is some other fast analogue of `"NOT IN"` in SQL. 
I hope for help. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the (generic) [set-difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Relative_complement) [`.Except()` LINQ method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except) to work, the two enumerables ([`IEnumerable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1)) passed as arguments must:

- enumerate instances of the same type `T`

  - However, it is possible to use `Object` for `T`, thereby effectively supporting PowerShell's *potentially mixed-type* regular `Object[]` arrays (`[object[]]` in PowerShell's type-literal notation).
- and, if that type is a *reference type* whose instance should compare meaningfully based on the *content* of instances (rather than by mere *reference equality*, i.e. identity), must implement the `IEquatable<T>` interface and/or override the `.Equals()` method (and therefore also the `.GetHashCode()` method).

PowerShell is seemingly not able to find the right overload for `.Except()` with the `[object[]]` arrays returned by `$Table1.FindName1` and `$Table2.FindName1`  (also see the note re v7.3+ below), though these arrays technically fulfill the above requirements - I don't know why.

However, simply casting one of these arrays to what it already is - `[object[]]` - solves the problem:

```bash
[Linq.Enumerable]::Except([object[]] $Table1.FindName1, $Table2.FindName1)
```

Note:

- As shown above, it is sufficient to cast *one* of the enumerables to `[object[]]` in order for PowerShell to infer the correct generic type argument for the method.

  - In [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) **7.3+** it is now possible to **call generic methods with *explicit* type arguments** (see [about_Calling_Generic_Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calling_generic_methods)), which allows simplifying the solution to:

    ```bash
    # Note the '[object]' right after 'Except',
    # specifying the generic type argument.
    [Linq.Enumerable]::Except[object]($Table1.FindName1, $Table2.FindName1)
    ```
- Given that the `.FindName1` column ultimately contains *strings*, you can also cast - both - enumerables to `[string[]]`, though this implicitly creates a *copy* of each array, which is unnecessary here.

---

Now if you want to **return *whole rows* while using the `.FindName1` column only for *comparison***, things get much more complex:

- You must implement a **custom comparer class** that implements the `IEqualityComparer[T]`interface.
- You must cast the `.Rows` collection of the data tables to `IEnumerable[DataRow]`, which requires calling the `System.Linq.Enumerable.Cast()` method *via reflection* (again, see further below for a simpler v7.3+ solution).

  - Note: While you could directly cast to `[DataRow[]]`, this would involve inefficient conversion of the rows collection to an array.

Here's a PSv5+ solution that implements the custom comparer class as a PowerShell class:

```bash
# A custom comparer class that compares two DataRow instances by their
# .FindName1 column.
class CustomTableComparer : Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer[Data.DataRow] {
  [bool] Equals([Data.DataRow] $x, [Data.DataRow] $y) {
    return [string]::Equals($x.FindName1, $y.FindName1, 'Ordinal')
  }
  [int] GetHashCode([Data.DataRow] $row) {
    # Note: Any two rows for which Equals() returns $true must return the same
    #       hash code. Because *ordinal, case-sensitive* string comparison is
    #       used above, it's sufficient to simply call .GetHashCode() on
    #       the .FindName1 property value, but that would have to be tweaked
    #       for other types of string comparisons.
    return $row.FindName1.GetHashCode();
  }
}


# Use reflection to get a reference to a .Cast() method instantiation 
# that casts to IEnumerable<DataRow>.
$toIEnumerable = [Linq.Enumerable].GetMethod('Cast').MakeGenericMethod([Data.DataRow])

# Call .Except() with the casts and the custom comparer.
# Note the need to wrap the .Rows value in an aux. single-element
# array - (, ...) - for it to be treated as a single argument.
[Linq.Enumerable]::Except(
    $toIEnumerable.Invoke($null, (, $Table1.Rows)), 
    $toIEnumerable.Invoke($null, (, $Table2.Rows)), 
    [CustomTableComparer]::new()
)
```

**PowerShell 7.3+ simplification**:

The ability to specify generic method type arguments directly makes the reflection-based approach unnecessary and simplifies the approach:

```bash
[Linq.Enumerable]::Except[Data.DataRow](
  [Linq.Enumerable]::Cast[Data.DataRow]($Table1.Rows), 
  [Linq.Enumerable]::Cast[Data.DataRow]($Table2.Rows), 
  [CustomTableComparer]::new()
)
```

Note: The `[Linq.Enumerable]::Cast[Data.DataRow]()` calls are still needed, because the `.Rows` property of `System.Data.DataTable` instances implements only `IEnumerable`, not also `IEnumerable[System.Data.DataRow]`.

---

[GitHub issue #2226](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2226) proposes making LINQ a first-class PowerShell citizen.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's like what I was looking for =)
`Compare-Object`  method from second message is too slow for my task

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful, @VasiliyPupkin, Yeah, I'm not surprised that `Compare-Object` is too slow.

Comment: In regard for the need to cast arrays as `[object[]]`, does that force PowerShell to uses the correct method for `[Linq.Enumerable]::Except(<parameters>)`?  In experimenting with `$Except = ([Enumerable].GetMethods() | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "Except" -and $_.IsGenericMethod })[0].MakeGenericMethod([string])`, I discovered that `[Linq.Enumerable].GetMethods().Name` offers 2 versions of `Except`.  Unfortunately, even if I'm correct, and it is using the wrong method, I still don't really understand why this is happening.  Your thoughts on this?

Comment: I think I partially answered my own question, and now thinking the answer is no.  Both methods are generic and accept a different number of arguments.

Comment: @Darin, [`System.Linq.Enumerable.Except`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Linq.Enumerable.Except) has only 2 overloads (you can see their signatures directly with `[Linq.Enumerable]::Except`), and only one of them takes exactly 2 arguments , so it's not clear to me why the cast is needed. It PS v7.3+, which now supports generic method calls explicitly, you can get away without the explicit cast, but only with `[object]` as the type: `[Linq.Enumerable]::Except[object](@('foo', 'bar'), @('bar', 'baz'))`

Comment: Thank you.  And sorry I wasted your time, I should have looked a little deeper.  And perhaps I should make the transition to the newest PS.

Comment: No worries, @Darin - this is complex stuff. Yes, PowerShell 7+ has many nice improvements, though I'd wait until at least v.7.4.1 to get the latest.

Answer (score 1):

To complement the [LINQ-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54964409/45375) with a **native PowerShell solution**:

The [`Compare-Object` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object) allows you to compare collections, but note that while it is **more concise**, it is also **much slower than the LINQ-based solution**:

```bash
Compare-Object -PassThru -Property FindName1 `
  ([Data.DataRow[]] $Table1.Rows) `
  ([Data.DataRow[]] $Table2.Rows) | Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '<='
```

- Casting `[Data.DataRow[]]` - which creates a new array from the rows collection - is seemingly needed for `Compare-Object` to recognize the rows as an enumerable.

  - Calling `.GetEnumerator()` or casting to `Collections.IEnumerable` doesn't help, and casting to `Collections.Generic.IEnumerable[Data.DataRow]]` fails.
- `-Property FindName1` specifies the comparison property, i.e., the property to compare the rows by.
- `-PassThru` is needed to make `Compare-Object` output the input objects as-is, instead of custom objects that contain only the property/ies specified with `-Property`.

  - Note that the objects are decorated with a `.SideIndicator` NoteProperty member, however, using PowerShell's ETS (extended type system) - see below.
- Given that `Compare-Object` outputs input objects that are unique to *either* collection, `Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '<='` must be used to limit the results to those difference objects that are unique to the LHS input collection (which is signaled via a `.SideIndicator` property value of `'<='` - the arrow points to the side the object is unique to).

[GitHub issue #4316](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4316) proposes a number of improvements to the `Compare-Object` cmdlet, which could help simplify and speed up the above solution.
That said, the proposal to [make LINQ a first-class PowerShell citizen, #2226](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2226), holds much more promise.